# Syntax error on token "void", @ expected for entry method declaration

Tags: java, methods, void

I'm trying to do an assignment for `Turtle` in `Dr. Java`.

I'm getting this compilation **error**:

> Syntax error on token "void", @ expected

for this line that I understood as "that line you just gotta write at the top":

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

**13 errors** came up for this.

After some internet search, I added a `public class` code line before it:

```
public class Turtle {
```

Errors magically reduced to **2 errors**. But one of those **errors** is:

> The type Turtle is already defined

Does anyone know what's going on with this error?

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class Turtle {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       World myWorld = new World ();
       Turtle turt1 = new Turtle(20, 300, myWorld);

       turt1.drawHello();
   }
}
```

Edit:
1. Yes I am adding my code to an existing class called Turtle.java according to the assignment instructions.
2. My code is added to the section in **Turtle.java** that replaces the original code of:

```
World earth = new World();
    Turtle t1 = new Turtle(earth);
    t1.forward();
```

My code is basically moving the turtle around to draw lines to make up a 5 lettered word.

3. I thought the error log was the error I posted on top? I got it from DrJava's Compiler output panel. Do you have instructions on how I can get to the error log?

Comment: 1) Adding the class declaration did not make it work by "magic" and; 2) then there must already a same-named class defined (again, not magic).

Comment: Your questions is not clear. Do you have another class named Turtle in your package. There can be one and only Turtle class within same package. Are you importing turtle from external library? Rename your own  class from Turtle to something else. Post your error log.

Answer (score -1):

> Syntax error on token "void", @ expected

Those instructions must be written separate and at the start of the class.